# Does the series $∑\frac {8n}{(\log n)^n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus

does the series $\sum \frac{8n}{(\log n)^n}$ converge or diverge? I've 'tried' using the root test but I just can't seem to get my head around the log in the denominator and what rules to apply because of it. Can anyone help me out here please? Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is the denominator?

Comment: (Lnn)^n ... my bad i wrote it wrong, going to try edit the orgiginal now...

Comment: I've tried to edit the question.. it is now correct or did you mean something else?

Comment: log composed n times or log power n ?

Comment: $\sum \frac{8n}{(logn)^n}$ <---

Comment: $2<\log (n)$ from some point on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the series converges; the root test yields

$$\lim \frac{\sqrt[n]{8n}}{\log n} = \lim \frac{1}{\log n} = 0 $$

Since the limit is $< 1$ the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

If
$e < a < b$,
then
$a^b > b^a
$.
Therefore,
for
$n > e^e$,
since
$e < \ln n < n$,
$(\ln n)^n
> n^{\ln n}
$
so
$\frac1{(\ln n)^n}
< \frac1{n^{\ln n}}
$.

Therefore
$\frac{n}{(\ln n)^n}
< \frac{n}{n^{\ln n}}
= \frac{1}{n^{\ln n-1}}
$.

Since
$\sum \frac{1}{n^{\ln n-1}}
$ converges
(since
$\ln n - 1 > 1$
for $n > e^2$),
so does
$\sum \frac{n}{(\ln n)^n}
$.

Comment: what is 'e'? is it Epsilon or Euler's number

Comment: Euler's number, 2.71828...